# Usage of "baking" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The [baking](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baking) tag reads:

> Baking is the act of pre-computing something in order to speed up some other process later down the line. Use this tag for Blender's bake feature under the Render panel.

Is it also okay to use this tag in reference to issues in baking physics systems? This seems to fall under the description of "pre-computing something … to speed up some other process later."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote the [original excerpt](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/1852/revisions) for this tag, so the limitation you are asking about is my fault. I neglected the fact that it could be *explicitly* open to all types of baking such as fluid sims, smoke etc so yes, it can be used. Feel free to edit it accordingly and if anything else comes to mind, it will be added as well.

Comment: All right, thanks.