# Confusion of “baking” and “texture-baking” tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I have noticed several questions lately about *texture baking* that have used the [baking] tag instead of [texture-baking].  The tag wikis make sufficient difference between the two:

Baking tag wiki:

> Baking is the act of pre-computing something in order to speed up some other process later down the line. Use this tag for baking any *physics simulations*.

Texture-Baking tag wiki:

> Questions about blender's Bake feature under the Render panel, such baked images as normal maps, AO maps, and displacement maps, and texture maps.

But unfortunately a lot of people don't actually seem read the wikis.

So I am wondering if there is anything that can be done about this confusion (albeit this isn't exactly super important).  Can the [baking] tag's name be changed to something like [physics-baking]?  Or if this isn't a problem, should the [baking] tag always be used along with [texture-baking]?

I am aware of [this](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253/usage-of-baking-tag) meta question, but it seems that the “Use this tag for baking any physics simulations.” has been added since then.  I do think it is a good idea to have two separate tags since baking physics and textures are quite different procedures.

A couple of examples of the confusion are [textures bake transparency as white](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15185/textures-bake-transparency-as-white) and [how to improve ambient occlusion in cycles...](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14965/how-to-improve-ambient-occlusion-in-cycles-and-reduce-pixelation-tearing), I have suggested edits on these types of questions before.

Answer (score 4):

When you find a question like the two you linked to, edit them and change the tags. There were many old questions that confused the two tags before we made a distinction. We had a discussion a while back in the chat about [baking](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baking) and [texture-baking](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texture-baking). Both of the question you linked are over a month old, I have not seen many recent questions with the wrong baking use. At this point I do not think it is needed to re name the tag, just fix the missed tagged question when you find them.